# TFrecord pre-process data before feeding to a model

Tags: tensorflow

I have a TFrecord file that consist of such features

```
features = {
  'features': tf.FixedLenFeature([17920], tf.float32),
  'video_id': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
  'split_id': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
  'audio': tf.FixedLenFeature([44100], tf.float32)
}
```

The way I currently get the iterator is as such:

```
 def getiterator(batch_size, decode_parallel_calls=1,repeat=False,
    shuffle=False,
    shuffle_buffer_size=None,
    prefetch_size=None,
    prefetch_gpu_num=None):
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(['../main.tfrecords'])

  # Shuffle all filepaths every epoch
  if shuffle:
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=sum(1 for _ in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator('../main.tfrecords')))

  # Repeat
  if repeat:
    dataset = dataset.repeat()

  # Shuffle examples
  if shuffle:
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size)

  def extract_fn(data_record):
    features = {
      'features': tf.FixedLenFeature([17920], tf.float32),
      'video_id': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
      'split_id': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      'audio': tf.FixedLenFeature([44100], tf.float32)
    }
    return tf.parse_single_example(data_record, features)

  dataset = dataset.map(extract_fn, num_parallel_calls=decode_parallel_calls)

  # Make batches
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)

  # Get tensors
  iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

  return iterator.get_next()
```

One thing that I am interested in doing is preprocessing the audio data by downsampling to 16000Hz. However, I am not sure how to do it so as I currently only get Tensors. What would be a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply place your downsampling logic inside `extract_fn`.

```
def extract_fn(data_record):
    features = {
      'features': tf.FixedLenFeature([17920], tf.float32),
      'video_id': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
      'split_id': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      'audio': tf.FixedLenFeature([44100], tf.float32)
    }
    features_in = tf.parse_single_example(data_record, features)

    # This is your audio tensor before downsampling.
    audio_tensor = features_in['audio'] 
    # Doing something to downsample audio_tensor
    downsampled_audio_tensor = do_something(audio_tensor)

    # Now I assume you need every other tensors as is, but replace the audio with
    # the one we downsampled above.
    features_out = {
      'features': features_in['features'],
      'video_id': features_in['video_id'],
      'split_id': features_in['split_id'],
      'audio': downsampled_audio_tensor,
    }
    return features_out
```

Comment: A follow-up question if you don't mind. How can I get the raw 'audio' data from the tensor so that I can downsample the audio? Would I need to eval() the tensor through a tf.Session()? Thank you a lot for the help!

Comment: I tried using .numpy() on the `audio_tensor` but it doesn't seem like its a method.

Comment: IIUC, your audio_tensor is a float tensor of shape [44100]. I have no idea how you organize your audio data into this list of floats, which could lead to different logic of downsampling. You should not use numpy method inside `extract_fn`. Please use tf.XXX methods to operate on tensors. But in case you need to decode the audio data first, take a look at `tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio` or `tf.decode_wav` or anything alike that is compatible with your audio format.

Comment: Thank you, I misunderstood how Tensors worked. I'll mark this question as solved.